# How to add texture to end of extruded object?

Tags: texturing, extrude

I'm new to blender, and probably just don't know what to search for.

I am trying to add a wooden texture to the end of the white extruded profile. 
But i'm not able to follow any of the guides I have found. 
It is like I'm missing a step before I'm allowed to select the end face of the white profile.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Brian

[image: 2D profile view]
[image: Extruded profiles]

[image: Wire frame view]

Comment: Your object is a bezier curve, you can't really "select faces" to apply materials like in mesh objects. Either apply a texture to the whole spline, or convert to a mesh if you really require just one face. Beware that this is a destructive process, and you should keep an original in a separate layer/scene for safe keeping. You can also make a shader that masks textures by normal

Comment: Thanks.
Saved a new file and managed to convert to mesh and apply an image as texture.